# How to create a temporary table in MS Access that originates from a SQL query in VB.NET?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, temp-tables

How to create a temporary table in MS Access that originates from a SQL query in VB.NET?

Is there a temporary table when the form is loaded? Do you add double records or do you need to empty the table first and then refill it?, please guide.

Temporary table named in MS Access : `MyTempTable`

```vb
 Public Sub jokenselect(ByVal sql As String)
        Try
            con.Open()
            With cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = sql
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        End Try
        con.Close()
        da.Dispose()
    End Sub
   Public Sub jokendelete(ByVal sql As String)
        Try
            con.Open()
            With cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = sql
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
                If result = 0 Then
                    MsgBox("No Data has been Updated!")
                    'Else
                    '    MsgBox("New Data is updated succesfully!")
                End If
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)

        End Try
        con.Close()

    End Sub
 Public Sub filltable(ByVal dtgrd As Object, ByVal design As String)
        Dim publictable As New DataTable
        Try
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(publictable)
            dtgrd.DataSource = publictable
            Select Case design
                Case "EmpInfo"
                    dtgrd.Columns(0).Visible = False
                Case "EmpPic"
                    dtgrd.MultiSelect = False
                    dtgrd.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
                    dtgrd.ReadOnly = True
                    dtgrd.Columns(0).Visible = False
            Case "Temp"
 End Select
            da.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        End Try
    End Sub
  jokendelete("Delete * FROM MyTempTable")
  jokenselect("ALTER TABLE MyTempTable ALTER COLUMN ID COUNTER(1,1)")
        filltable(DataGridView3, "Temp")
        jokenselect("INSERT INTO MyTempTable (EMPID, [NAME],[TOTAL CPI])
        SELECT
        EC.EMPID
        ,E.[NAME]
        ,format(EC.SKILL/(select MIN(MINSKILL.SKILL) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCSKILL/100 from tblWeightingCriteria)+EC.EXPERIENCE/(select MIN(MINSKILL.EXPERIENCE) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCEXPERIENCE/100 from tblWeightingCriteria)+EC.APPEARANCE/(select MIN(MINSKILL.APPEARANCE) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCAPPEARANCE/100 from tblWeightingCriteria)+EC.EDUCATION/(select MIN(MINSKILL.EDUCATION) from tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100*(select WCEDUCATION/100 from tblWeightingCriteria),'#,##0.00') as [TOTAL CPI]
        FROM tblEmployeeCriteria EC
        INNER JOIN tblemployee E ON EC.EMPID = E.EMPID
        ORDER BY 3 DESC")
        filltable(DataGridView3, "Temp")
        jokenselect("SELECT [NAME], format([Total CPI],'#,##0.00') AS [Total CPI] FROM MyTempTable;")
        filltable(DataGridView3, "TEMP")
```

Comment: Tables in Access are persistent. You''ll have to clean it up before refilling it.

Comment: @Gustav , thanks for your response, how can i do according to the recommendation please guide me

Comment: It should be simple: Open the table and delete all entries, or run a basic Delete query on the table.

Comment: @Gustav , if you don't mind can you provide an answer create a temporary table from the sql query code that I posted and then delete and refill again

Comment: Sorry, I always use the _DataTableAdapters_ to avoid low level code, but there are dozens of examples out there available for the browsing.

Comment: @Gustav , from my query above is it possible to go directly to the temporary table

Comment: Somehow you can expand it to this, I guess, though I see no reference to the temp table.

Comment: @Gustav , Thank you for your response. Sorry if I'm late replying. I have updated the code that I posted maybe my method is wrong then I need a guide from you

Comment: I see no `jokendelete` function but somehow you must _execute_ the delete and alter commands. I'm not familiar with VB.NET but, again, there are lots of example code to find out there.

Comment: @Gustav , sorry I already updated the code function in the post